# Replicate Base64 decoding of Java in PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, base64

I am trying to get the same result I am getting in Java when decoding a Base64 String (`NVARCHAR2`) in Oracle.

I do have the following String: `N'AAECAwQFBgdNu+qx2ZcqsA=='` which is basically a encrypted password packed into a Base64 encoding.

In Java I am doing this:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(testValue.getBytes());
for(byte b: bytes){
     System.out.print(String.valueOf(b & 0xFF) + " "); //Decimal (unsigned)    
}
for(byte b: bytes){
     System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + " "); //Hex 
}
```

which prints me following:

```
Unsigned: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 77 187 234 177 217 151 42 176 
Hex:      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 4d bb  ea  b1  d9  97  2a b0
```

Now I want to replicate the Base64 decoding like it's made in Java. I am trying following in a PL/SQL-Function:

```
base64DecodedInput:= UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(valueToDecrypt, charset));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Base64 decoded is: ' || base64DecodedInput);
```

The charset is: AL16UTF16
and valueToDecrypt is the test String I mentioned above as `NVARCHAR2(200)`

The DBMS_OUTPUT prints me:

```
Base64 decoded is: 0000004200300105A8308FDD02FE02B11B7901EA02C0
```

Which is wrong!...

What did I miss. Is PL/SQL not using url safe decoding or whatever?

I am stuck.

The code is part of a PL/SQL-Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decodeBase64
(valueToDecrypt IN NVARCHAR2)
RETURN NVARCHAR2
AS
   --Declaration area
   charset VARCHAR(100);
   base64DecodedInput RAW(2000); 
   ...
```

And Server/Database Settings are:

```
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   12.1.0.2.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [CAST_TO_RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71383) Ddocumentation:

> This function converts a **VARCHAR2** value represented using some number of data bytes into a RAW value with that number of data bytes.

You should use this one:

```
base64DecodedInput:= UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(TO_CHAR(valueToDecrypt)));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Base64 decoded is: ' || base64DecodedInput);

00010203040506074DBBEAB1D9972AB0
```

Which (formatted) should be equal to desired result:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 4D BB EA B1 D9 97 2A B0
```

It is quite useless to use `NVARCHAR2` for a BASE64 string. The main purpose of BASE64 encoding is to represent arbitrary data only with ASCII characters, so NVARCHAR2 makes no sense. Since BASE64 contains only ASCII you don't have to worry about any character encoding at `CAST(... AS VARCHAR2(200))`.

Of course, for the **decoded** string data type `NVARCHAR2` might be very useful.

Comment: You are completely right, but to keep coding conventions of the company the data has to be saved this way.

Comment: How do you format it? I still get: Base64 decoded is: 0000004200300105A8308FDD02FE02B11B7901EA02C0 using your code...

Comment: `test varchar2(200);`
`test:= CAST(valueToDecrypt AS VARCHAR2(200));`
Is getting me the same error

Comment: Looks like `CAST(... AS VARCHAR2(200))` does not work in PL/SQL, try `TO_CHAR(valueToDecrypt)`

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to what @Wernfried answered would be to use conversion not casting.

As Java is printing UTF-8 values in this example you have to convert the NVARCHAR2 as well to UTF-8 before decoding it.

```
base64DecodedInput:= UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(valueToDecrypt, conversionCharset));
```