# Replicate Pl/Sql Base64 decoding to java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, base64

I have the following Oracle statement which I need to convert to Java.

```
select utl_encode.base64_decode('2B563967613057553550327651324B6A50756C38766F3149424E69644B6D69394A5872736C773D3D') from dual;
```

Output should be :

```
F95F606B4594E4FDAF4362A33EE97CBE8D4804D89D2A68BD257AEC97.
```

I tried using Base64.decodeBase64 but the output is not same as above.

Also tried the following link

[Replicate Base64 decoding of Java in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898285/replicate-base64-decoding-of-java-in-pl-sql/44900006#44900006?newreg=644162abad294a8d8b031894a16c5dbf)
but not very much helpful.

Java output :

`d81e7adfdebbeb5df4e7be79df9e74df6efae75df6e01e80e74ef9e82dfcefae85df5e3de36e04ebdeb8e01e83ebddfde00e7cef6ef7e82efbdc3dc3`

Can anybody help.

Comment: what was the output then?

Comment: The input you show does not look like Base64.  It looks like a hexadecimal representation of a Base64 string.

Comment: String output is as below : �z�޻�]��yߞt�n��]����N��-�ﮅ�^=�n�޸������|�n��.��=� which is encoded form so I convert it to hex to verify. But I am not sure is that the right way?

Comment: @user9054598 See my answer

Answer (score 0):

The input you provided is the *hexadecimal representation* of a Base64 string, not the actual Base64 string. The following code will give the result you are looking for:

```
    String data = "2B563967613057553550327651324B6A50756C38766F3149424E69644B6D69394A5872736C773D3D";

    // Quick-n-dirty method to convert hex string back to bytes
    // Doesn't work if hex string has leading zeros, but for this case that doesn't apply
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(data,16);
    byte[] bdata = bi.toByteArray();

    // Let's look at the real Base64 string...
    String temp = new String(bdata);
    System.out.println("The base64 string is:          " + temp);

    // Now decode the base64 string back to bytes        
    byte[] result = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bdata);

    // Finally print the hex representation of the decoded value
    System.out.print("The decoded value (in hex) is: ");
    for (byte b : result)
        System.out.printf("%02x", 0x000000ff & (int)b);
    System.out.println();
```

This outputs:

```
The base64 string is:          +V9ga0WU5P2vQ2KjPul8vo1IBNidKmi9JXrslw==
The decoded value (in hex) is: f95f606b4594e4fdaf4362a33ee97cbe8d4804d89d2a68bd257aec97
```